# Tfs 2015 agent build getting sources not enough space on disc

Tags: azure, tfs

When running a new build on certain repositories, the build dies when "getting sources" before the first step in my build definition. The error returned is not enough space on disk. 
I've tried to add a clean or delete step but they wont execute unless getting sources succeeds. Also I tried to clear the repo on a definition that is building without any luck. 
Is there anything I can do from the TFS web page to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Are you using XAML build or JSON build? There are some things that can be done to mitigate the problem, but it's dependent on knowing those things. The easiest solution is to add more disk space to the build agents.

Comment: @DanielMann I believe its json. The only reason I say that is because a few logs had some json exceptions concerning disk space. I'm a total noob and dont know much about the build server other than what i can see through TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you are getting "not enough space in disk error" it might mean that
>   **the amount of disk space used by your source code** (files, repos, branches, etc), **together with the amount of disk space taken by your
>   build output** (files generated as a result of the build process) **is
>   crossing the space** provided by your system which your agent located.

When getting this error you should remote to the machine holding your build agent. Find the system drive and clear up no need files to release space.

It could well be too many or too big files being generated by the build or also source code. That is, you just need to find out which one of these two is the cause of your lack of disk space, and work on freeing it.

If you have no idea which kind of folder you are able to delete. You could take a look at *Jason Williams's* answer in this question: [TFS Build Server Disk Space Issue, is it ok to delete folder under Build Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114750/tfs-build-server-disk-space-issue-is-it-ok-to-delete-folder-under-build-directo)

Comment: Thank you for your help. We deleted as much as we could and doubled the disc size which instantly fixed the problem.